# Get Authorize.Net transaction detail with the refId

Tags: authorize.net

I am passing the order id from my website to the Authorize.Net as `refid` but when i try to get the transaction by passing `refid` in `getTransactionDetailsRequest` method then it is not recognizable.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: no answer help at all

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: still unable to solve

Comment: Are you still trying to use refId? Have you tried using the transactionId?

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-details) you will see you cannot retrieve transaction information using the `refId` value. You *must* pass the transaction ID to successfully retrieve a transactions. Passing the `refId`:

> If included in the request, this value is included in the response. This feature might be especially useful for multi-threaded applications.

But it cannot be using in place of a transaction ID.