# Need to pass SaleID to Authorize.Net and have it echo back in Response

Tags: vb.net, authorize.net

I am working with the Authorize.Net SDK and have it working properly in a VB.Net version of the code that calls the AuthorizeNet.dll supplied in the GitHub SDK.

I want to add the feature of sending a saleID and getting it back in the response as is described in the on-line documentation.  If I understand correctly "refid" does exactly that. I inserted refid in my code as shown below.

```
 Dim request = New createTransactionRequest With {
                .transactionRequest = transactionRequest,
                .refId = "CARL:123456"
            }
```

The request works fine and the transaction is approved.  However, the saleID is not sent back as promised in the documentation.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong because I feel it is very important to prevent "bad things" from happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Authorize.Net transaction detail with the refId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753776/get-authorize-net-transaction-detail-with-the-refid)

Comment: No help at all.